# SQLAlchemy query.first() finds next entry each new time query function executed

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Im running a scrapy spider in flask and using flask-SQLAlchemy to add data to a postgres db. The spider has a `process_item` function that is executed each time data is collected from a website. Each time a website is scraped, the website is added to a `merchants` table and gets assigned a unique id. This id is stored in a variable `merchant_id` and is used as a relationship to find the first entry in the `requisites` table in order to update one of the 11 columns of the table.

This is the function im using

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    requisite = Requisites.query.filter_by(merchant_id=self.merchant_id).first()
    if requisite:
        print(f"requisite True - {requisite}")
        for key in item:
            exec(f"requisite.{key} = item['{key}']")
            db.session.commit()
    else:
        print(f"requisite False - {requisite}")
        requisite = Requisites(website=self.website, merchant_id=self.merchant_id)
        db.session.add(requisite)
        for key in item:
            exec(f"requisite.{key} = item['{key}']")
            db.session.commit()
    return item
```

In my `requisites` table I have in total five entries with the same `merchant_id`. Each of these entries has its own unique id in the `requisites` table.
I noticed that the first record get populated only the first time the `process_item` is executed. So I added `print(f"requisite True - {requisite}")` to the function and noticed that each time it is executed the query returns the next entry from the requisites table and not the first, although i've used .first(). Why this is happening and how to solve this?
This is what gets printed each time `process_item` gets executed:

```
requisite True - <Requisites 3>
requisite True - <Requisites 4>
requisite True - <Requisites 5>
requisite True - <Requisites 6>
```

This is how the `requisites` table looks like
[image]

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but can use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) instead of `exec` in your code - using `exec` for setting attributes isn't best practice.  if you want a specific record returned when there's more than one match then you should order the query, for example `Requisites.query.filter_by(merchant_id=self.merchant_id).order_by(Requisite.id).first()`.  Even better would be add a separate column - such as a timestamp - to avoid depending on the `id` column.

Comment: the order_by resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: @snakechamber regarding setattr it seems that it is useful only for updating the whole objects (row queried) attributes, but in my case I need to update a particular column of a particular row and I get  the value of the column from looping dict keys

Comment: You should be able to replace your `for` loop with `for k, v in item.items():setattr(requisite, k, v)` (assuming `item` is a `dict`).